# Merge Two Guava Multimaps

Tags: java, merge, java-stream, guava, multimap

Is there a way to elegantly merge two guava multimaps with the same key value pairs in java 8?

I have tried using .collect(Multimaps.toMultimap()) with no luck.

Comment: What's wrong with `putAll()`?

Comment: Sorry should have said flatten a list of Multimaps.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a few ways; this is the cleanest one I could find:

```
list.stream().collect(ArrayListMultimap::create, Multimap::putAll, Multimap::putAll)
```

Feel free to replace `ArrayListMultimap` with some other implementation.